# I keep getting (Suspended(NullPointerException)) when I try to run my game, but I cant find the error anywhere

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I keep getting an error in my code but I cant find it anywhere, it started when I added the Spritesheet and my Screen class, here's the stack:

```
Thread [Thread-2] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
Screen.render(int[], int, int) line: 51 
Game.render() line: 128 
Game.run() line: 101    
Thread.run() line: not available
```

`

And Line 51 is this line:

```
int colour = tileIndex * 4 + sheet.pixels[sheetPixel++];
```

And this is the Screen class:

```
package ca.vanzeben.game.gfx;

public class Screen {

    public static final int MAP_WIDTH = 64;
    public static final int MAP_WIDTH_MASK = MAP_WIDTH - 1 ;

    public int[] tiles = new int[MAP_WIDTH*MAP_WIDTH];
    public int[] colours = new int[MAP_WIDTH*MAP_WIDTH*4];

    public int xOffset = 0;
    public int yOffset = 0;

    public int width;
    public int height;

    public SpriteSheet sheet;

    public Screen(int width, int height, SpriteSheet sheet) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.sheet = sheet;

        for (int i = 0; i<MAP_WIDTH*MAP_WIDTH; i++) {
            colours [i*4+0] = 0xff00ff;
            colours [i*4+1] = 0x00ffff;
            colours [i*4+2] = 0xffff00;
            colours [i*4+3] = 0xffffff;
        }
    }

    public void render(int[] pixels, int offset, int row) {
        for (int yTile = yOffset >>3;yTile <= (yOffset+height)>>3;yTile++) {
            int yMin = yTile * 8 - yOffset;
            int yMax = yMin + 8;
            if (yMin < 0) yMin = 0;
            if (yMax > height) yMax = height;

            for (int xTile = xOffset >>3;xTile <= (xOffset+width)>>3;xTile++) {
                int xMin = xTile * 8 - xOffset;
                int xMax = xMin + 8;
                if (xMin < 0) xMin = 0;
                if (xMax > width) xMax = width;

                int tileIndex = (xTile & (MAP_WIDTH_MASK))+ (yTile &(MAP_WIDTH_MASK))*MAP_WIDTH;

                for (int y = yMin; y <yMax; y++) {
                    int sheetPixel = ((y + yOffset)& 7)* sheet.width + ((xMin + xOffset) & 7);
                    int tilePixel = offset + xMin + y*row;
                    for (int x = xMin; x<xMax; x++) {
                        int colour = tileIndex * 4 + sheet.pixels[sheetPixel++];
                        pixels [tilePixel++] = colours [colour];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Game class:

```
package ca.vanzeben.game;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH /12*9;
    public static final int SCALE =3;
    public static final String NAME = "Wake Me Up";

    private JFrame frame;

    public boolean running = false;
    public int tickCount = 0;

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage     (WIDTH,HEIGHT,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private int[] pixels =((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    private Screen screen;

    public Game() {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension (WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension (WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension (WIDTH*SCALE,HEIGHT*SCALE));

        frame = new JFrame(NAME);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        frame.add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void init() {
        screen = new Screen (WIDTH,HEIGHT, new SpriteSheet("/sprite_sheet.xcf"));
    }


    public synchronized void start() {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();

    }

    public synchronized void stop() {

    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000D/60D;

        int frames = 0;
        int ticks = 0;

        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = 0;

        init();

        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now-lastTime) / nsPerTick;
            lastTime = now;
            boolean shouldRender = true;

            while (delta >=1) {
                ticks++;
                tick();
                delta -= 1;
                shouldRender = true;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (shouldRender) {
                frames++;
                render();
            }

            if (System.currentTimeMillis()-lastTimer>=1000) {
                lastTimer += 1000;
                System.out.println(ticks+ "," +frames);
                frames = 0;
                ticks = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public void tick() {
        tickCount++;    

        for (int i=0; i < pixels.length;i++) {
            pixels[i] = i+tickCount;
        }
    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        screen.render(pixels, 0, WIDTH);

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new Game().start();
    }

}
```

And here is the SpriteSheet class:

```
package ca.vanzeben.game.gfx;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteSheet {

    public String path;
    public int width;
    public int height;

    public int [] pixels;

    public SpriteSheet(String path) {
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {

            image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (image == null) {
            return;
        }

        this.path = path;
        this.width = image.getWidth();
        this.height = image.getHeight();

        pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

        for(int i = 0; i< pixels.length;i++) {
            pixels[i] = (pixels[i] & 0xff)/64;
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<8;i++) {
            System.out.println(pixels[i]);
        }
    }  
}
```

Usually I dont ask for help but I just can find the error anywhere. Thank you!

Comment: You'll get considerably more attention for your question if you tag it with the language you're using and any appropriate libraries.

Comment: Use your debugger to break on a NPE and find out what at the given line has the value `null`.

Comment: Without a (preferably short) self contained program (see http://sscce.org/) its hard to say what exactly is wrong beyond (as NPE says) sheet is "wrong" when its passed to the constructor, specifically sheet.pixels is null. Why its null would require the rest of the program

Comment: pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

Comment: There might be something with this sentence but I'm not sure, here' I've set something to null

Comment: @user2757088 Somewhere along the lines its gone wrong, beyond NPE's answer we can't go further without the whole program (main and all) or ideally a simplification of the whole program that still shows the problem (main and all) if your real program is big

Comment: So, you'll need my full code?

Comment: @user2757088 yes, or **preferably** a simplified version that still replicates the problem (remove irrelevant methods, classes etc)

Comment: Yeah, I can probably add the two other classes too

Comment: Does the println loop within the SpriteSheet constructor ever run? Because as far as I can see it, if there is any problem with the ImageIO.read then image will remain null, as such if (image == null) { return;} will return. This will leave SpriteSheet not fully initialised (pixels will be null)

Comment: You're right, the println doesnt run, I noticed this now, I forgot I even added it. Is there any solution to this problem (thanks for your help)

Comment: @user2757088 I thought so! As per my answer the problem is this line, "image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));", you're suppressing the IOException without dealing with it (bad bad idea!!! as you've found). Never allow your program to continue running in an unsafe state, terminate with a runtimeException if all else fails. Why ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path)); is having a problem will depend on exactly what its trying to read. Look at the rest of the stack trace thats printed by e.printStackTrace(); and see if it gives any clues

Comment: Nope, somehow it just wont work, I did use gimp to create my spritesheet and I dont think it liked that source...maybe I should use photoshop instead

Comment: @user2757088 It may be, the clue will be in the stack trace however (the first exception's)

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that `sheet.pixels` is `null` (if `sheet` itself were `null`, you'd get an NPE on an earlier line).

Comment: How do I fix this? (pretty new to programming, know the basics but still new)

Comment: @user2757088 that depends on how exactly SpriteSheet works but ideally its constructor should set pixels to something (because currently its being left as nothing aka null). Alternatively it might be being actively set to null. In which case you would need to find out where the null is coming from. Running through in debugger would help figure out where the null is coming from

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I can find for sheet.pixels being null at the indicated line is that the `ImageIO.read(...)` within the SpriteSheet constructor has excountered an IOException and has therefore left image as null.

```
public SpriteSheet(String path) {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path)); //<-- has an IOException problem
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (image == null) { //<--image remains null
        return; //<--- rest of constructor is skipped
    }
    this.path = path;
    this.width = image.getWidth();
    this.height = image.getHeight();

    pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);
    .... rest of constructor
```

Here if `image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));` encountered an IOException and image remains null then the next if statement simply terminates the SpriteSheet constructor failing to initialise a number of variables including pixels; leaving it null.

Having a constructor return a horrible not properly initialised object if it encounters a problem is a very bad idea unless you have a specific reason to do so; propagate the error if needs be or (if you don't want to deal with it properly; perhaps because you believe it will never come up) at least throw a runtime exception so if all else fails you at least know what went wrong. Leaving a not fully initialised object like this is much worse than an exception because it will still cause problems (and probably an exception later) but the exception will be far from the actual cause of the problem as you have found; or even worse it might not cause an exception later but just give a 'crazy' result which is even harder to diagnose.

Comment: so (if I understand this correctly) imge = ImageIO.read encountered a problem called ioexception, and therefore it terminated the next if statemen, leaving pixels null? that makes sense...Wish I could find a solution to this

Comment: @user2757088 The trouble is that the most likely reason for this is (a) the file doesn't exist or (b) it didn't 'like' the file. Neither of which I can diagnose from my end. Have a look at what the e.printStackTrace said and see if it offers any clues

Comment: P.s. whatever e.printStackTrace printed was the "real" exception, the one you've seen is just the collateral damage. Add whatever e.printStackTrace printed to your question as well